# Looking for a PrototypeJS Product Carousel Extension Recommendation

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, prototype-js

I'm looking for an extension recommendation for a product carousel which:

1. Functions via the PrototypeJS library (not jQuery)
2. Has the ability to display multiple slides at any single given time
3. Has the ability to skip multiple slides (i.e all visible slides)
4. Has the ability to slide continuously in a circular motionm, and lastly
5. Has the ability to auto scroll

I.E, if I want to display products:

a, b, c, d, e & f

The carousel would ideally display (as an example) 3 products at a time, so:

[a, b, c] slide [d, e, f] then back to [a, b, c] etc.

**Please do not recommend:** https://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/

This codepool has become abandoned, been split into multiple branches accross github and I haven't been able to find a single repository which has the five requirements as mentioned above. And yes, I have looked at the [Issues List and fixes applied](https://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/issues/list).

An ideal example can be found on any [www.dx.com](http://www.dx.com/p/bluedio-r-legend-version-bluetooth-4-0-hi-fi-headphone-w-8-ch-8-driver-nfc-tf-silver-347348#.VCuOFxawJ7s) product page, using either the:

- Customers Who Viewed This Item Also Viewed, or
- Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought carousels

Note that the first carousel on the example page does not have auto slide enabled, a feature which I am looking for.

The reason I'm looking for PrototypeJS specifically and **not** jQuery is because I'd like to avoid having to add another JS library next to Prototype, which is natively supported by Magento.

Comment: Have you found anything good?

Comment: Not yet but my hunt continues.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any of these so I cannot give more details about them but you can see if one fits your needs:

- http://miedlar.com/samples/carousel/sample. [Documentation](http://miedlar.com/dev/carousel)
- https://github.com/nyousefi/Prototype-Carousel - This is a modified version of the one you already tested. Maybe the issues are fixed in this one.